# Replace values in second df determined by first df - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate dataframes, the first is essentially a description of values and the second contains the actual values. I'm hoping to multiply values in the second df based on a certain grouping in the first df.

Specifically, for each unique `Time`, I'm interested in the Direction of `GR1`, which is the reference group. If `GR1` == `Group` & `Direction` == `down`, then multiply every row of `'Val1','Val2'` in `df2` by -1 for that unique `Time`.

For `Time` point `1` the `Group A` is `Up` so leave `df2` as is. For `Time` point `2`, `Group A` is `Down` so I want to multiply rows associated with both `Group A` and `Group B` in `df2` for cols `'Val1','Val2'` by -1. This pattern repeats for the remaining unique `Time` points.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],    
    'GR1' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],
    'GR2' : ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
    'Group' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],    
    'Direction' : ['Up','Down','Down','Up','Up','Down','Down','Up'],          
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],    
    'Group' : ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange'],
    'Val1' : [-2.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0],
    'Val2' : [-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,3.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0],              
   })

df.loc[(df['GR1'] == df['Group']) & (df['Direction'] == 'Down'), df2['Val1','Val2']] * -1
```

intended output:

```
    Time    Item  Val1  Val2
0      1     Red  -2.0  -2.0
1      1    Blue  -1.0  -1.0
2      1  Orange  -1.0  -2.0
3      2     Red   0.0   1.0 * Multiply by -1
4      2    Blue   0.0   2.0 * Multiply by -1
5      2  Orange  -1.0   1.0 * Multiply by -1
6      3     Red   0.0   0.0
7      3    Blue   1.0   1.0
8      3  Orange   2.0   3.0
9      4     Red   1.0   2.0 * Multiply by -1
10     4    Blue   0.0   1.0 * Multiply by -1
11     4  Orange   0.0   2.0 * Multiply by -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
q = 'GR1 == Group & Direction == "Down"'
mask = df2.Time.isin(df.query(q).Time)
df2.loc[mask, ['Val1', 'Val2']] *= -1

df2

    Time Group    Item  Val1  Val2
0      1     A     Red  -2.0  -2.0
1      1     B    Blue  -1.0  -1.0
2      1     A  Orange  -1.0  -2.0
3      2     A     Red  -0.0   1.0
4      2     B    Blue  -0.0   2.0
5      2     A  Orange  -1.0   1.0
6      3     A     Red   0.0   0.0
7      3     B    Blue   1.0   1.0
8      3     A  Orange   2.0   3.0
9      4     A     Red   1.0   2.0
10     4     B    Blue  -0.0   1.0
11     4     A  Orange  -0.0   2.0
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is a bit tricky to explain. For `Time` point `2` and `4` all rows in `Val, Val2` should be multiplied. Not just `Group A`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach working from your original solution:

```py
times = df.loc[(df['GR1'] == df['Group']) & (df['Direction'] == 'Down')]['Time']
df2.loc[df2['Time'].isin(times), ['Val1','Val2']] *= -1
```

Output:

```py
    Time Group    Item  Val1  Val2
0      1     A     Red  -2.0  -2.0
1      1     B    Blue  -1.0  -1.0
2      1     A  Orange  -1.0  -2.0
3      2     A     Red  -0.0   1.0
4      2     B    Blue  -0.0   2.0
5      2     A  Orange  -1.0   1.0
6      3     A     Red   0.0   0.0
7      3     B    Blue   1.0   1.0
8      3     A  Orange   2.0   3.0
9      4     A     Red   1.0   2.0
10     4     B    Blue  -0.0   1.0
11     4     A  Orange  -0.0   2.0
```